ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : calling WCF Bing service throws "Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,"
ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API calling WCF Bing Service throws the following when instantiate the proxy class:
Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,
I found System.Web.HttpContext in Dotnet framework as Microsoft website
Should we add dotnet Framewrok too to the Web API library
Please advise.

I tested it myself and didn't get any problems. First of all, I want to emphasize that System.Servicemodel is not supported in ASP.NET Core. However, in ASP.NET Core, we can use CoreWCF for further configuration. You can try installing CoreWCF libraries.
